# How to build request json correctly in Object Detection with Tensorflow REST API?

Tags: rest, tensorflow, request, tensorflow-serving, object-detection-api

I am trying to use an Object Detection based model with Tensorflow REST API. I already do that using GRPC mode. I input an base64 image parsed into a numpy array, as code bellow:

```
            #Converting to byte array
            image = base64.b64decode(input)

            #Now converting to numpy array
            nparr = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)

            #Decode into image object
            image = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

            #Expandind the array
            image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

            #Making the predict of image
            result = self._predict(image_expanded, label_map_string, num_classes, image)
```

So I call the predict method, which is where the grpc calls happens:

```
        stub = self._connection()
        result = None
        request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
        request.model_spec.name = self.lst_model_names[0]
        request.model_spec.signature_name = self.signature_name

        label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(label_map_string)
        categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=num_classes,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)
        category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

        request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
            tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(data))

        result = stub.Predict.future(request, self.timeout)
```

In the request object I have something like:

```
model_spec {
name: "object_detection"
signature_name: "serving_default"
}
inputs {
  key: "inputs"
  value {
    dtype: DT_UINT8
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: 1
      }
      dim {
        size: 720
      }
      dim {
        size: 1280
      }
      dim {
        size: 3
      }
    }
    tensor_content: "&/3 )-\037%*!\',#)..."
}
```

And it works perfectly in grpc.

For Tensorflow REST API I don't know how it should work.
I have built a payload like this:

```
{
"signature_name": "serving_default",
"inputs":{
    "inputs":[
        {
            "b64":""
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Passing the image input as base64 format.

What am I doing wrong?

Everytime I send the request i take the error:

```
Type: Object is not of expected type: uint8"
```

Is there something wrong with this structure?

How should I build the correct json to predict on Object Detection models?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure should be like this. "b64" is for base64 encoded image, but your input is of type uint8.

```
body = {
    "signature_name": "serving_default",
    "inputs": [
        image 
        ]
    }
```

Comment: It worked as well! I ovewrite the "image" for my 4 dimensional array.
Another approach that I used was that one: 

`{
 "signature_name": "serving_default",
 "inputs":{
  "inputs":[
   {
    "b64": image_array
   }
  ]
 }
}`

But now I am trying to find a way to make the request not that heavy, because 4 dim arrays are too heavy.